# JSOUP - find elements starting with

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have a following HTML:

```
<data-my-tag>
  <data-another-tag>
    <p>...</p>
    <data-my-tag>
      <span>...</span>
    </data-my-tag>
  </data-another-tag>
</data-my-tag>
```

I use JSOUP to parse it and I would like to match all elements starting with `<data-`.

I only found methods to match `getElementsByTag` which matches by entire tag name. Also `select` method performs only css selector, but there seems to be no way to match `data-*` in JSOUP way (e.g. use XPath). Is there any way to match these tags via JSOUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use XPath queries in JSOUP. The only way I figured out is following:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements elements = doc.select("*");

elements.stream().filter(e -> e.nodeName().startsWith("data-")).forEach(e -> {
    // do what you need with the node
});
```